# UITableViewCellについて

Tags: swift3

お願いします。

現在UITableViewCellの実装をしているのですが、一つのセルに２つの Labelを配置するには、どう設定すればよろしいですか？

Cell一つだと、

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let _cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier:cellIdentifier,for:indexPath) as UITableViewCell
    let cell = _cell
    cell.textLabel?.text = "a"
    return cell
}
```

でいけるのですが、もう一つ同じセル内に文字を表示させたい場合どのように実装すればよろしいですか？

---

＊＊＊追記＊＊＊
cellインスタンスを生成、
    `<変数名>:label = cell.viewWithTag(x) as? UILabel`
で、予め各オブジェクトにTag設定してviewWithTag()で指定するとできました。

追加でもう一つ質問お願いできますか？
MagicNumberとよく聞きますが、こういったコーティングは個人では問題ないでしょうが、自分以外の人たちが関わる開発等で今回のような、手法は有効になるでしょうか？それとも、もっと分かり易い効率的な手法があるでしょうか？？抽象的な質問かと思いますが、よろしくお願いします。

Comment: `tableView(:cellForRowAt:)`を実装するためには、 **`UITableViewCell`をそのまま使うのか、自前のサブクラスを定義するのか** 、**コードだけで実装するのかStoryboardに設定を入れておくのか** と言ったことで細部の書き方が変わってきます。テーブルビューのプログラミングはAppleから[公式ドキュメントの日本語版](https://developer.apple.com/jp/documentation/TableView_iPhone.pdf)も出ています。古いドキュメントですし、長大で今はまだ関係ないことまで解説されているので、それだけですぐに分かるはずとは言えませんが、まずはじっくりドキュメントを読まれた上で、自分がどのような表示を実現したいのか、現在はどのように実装しようとしているのかと言った情報をご質問に追記してください。

Comment: 早い回答ありがとうございます。今確認しました返答遅れ申し訳ないです。質問の複数Labelに関してですが、自己解決しました。追加で質問文下に追記‌​します。

Comment: 疑問が自己解決した場合、スタック・オーバーフローでは[自己回答](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer)が推奨されています。是非お願いします。また、質問の主題とあまり関係がない疑問は，別の質問としてご投稿ください。

Comment: label = cell.viewWithTag(x) as? UILabelでタグごとに文字列の設定ができました。遅らせながら御礼申し上げます。

Answer (score 0):

> MagicNumberとよく聞きますが、こういったコーティングは個人では問題ないでしょうが、自分以外の人たちが関わる開発等で今回のような、手法は有効になるでしょうか？

マジックナンバーで問題になるのは、「何故」そのようになっているのか、といったコードだけからは読み取れないという部分ですので、

1. 変数名で意図が伝わるようにする
   1.08 * price => (1 + tax) * price
2. そうなっている理由をコメントにきちんと書く

といった方法で回避可能です。

> 追加で質問文下に追記‌​します

再度質問し直したほうがタイトルなどを含め、回答を得やすくなるかと思います

Comment: 遅れ遅れすみません。わかりやすい返信ありがとうございます。コメントで回避覚えておきます。